# How to import C makefile project into eclipse or put in under eclipse

Tags: c++, c, linux, eclipse, makefile

I have standard source code package under Linux which requires to run

```
./configure
make
```

to compile it (and it works ok).

Mostly these files are C/C++

Is it possible to put this project under Eclipse control? I wish to browse definitions etc...

**UPDATE 1**

I have Eclipse Indigo running on Ubuntu. It contains CDT of course.

When I choose `File-Import`, I see no matching option under `C/C++`. Under `General` I have `Existing Projects into Workspace` but I get `No project are found to import` if I point this wizard to my project root.

**UPDATE 2**

I have installed Eclipse with Ubuntu package manager. Probably this was wrong.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First run the ./configure to generate the Makefile.
After that, if you have CDT installed,just choose the option
"File->New->Makefile Project With Existing Code" and point to the directory where the Makefile is stored.

Comment: I have no `File->New->Makefile Project With Existing Code` option. Probably I need to install Eclipse not with Ubuntu package manager.

Comment: Try File->New->Other-> Makefile Project with Existing Code.

Install CDT if you already haven't.

Comment: Is it ok to do `Import ->C/C++ -> Existing code as AutoTools project` ? Let eclipse run the ./configure ?

Comment: I download a Binutils tar package, I extract it to folder `binutils`. The Binutils documentation recommends `building Binutils in a dedicated build directory`, so I mkdir `binutils/build`, I run configure and get a Makefile in `binutils/build`. Then I `File->New->Makefile Project With Existing Code` and point to the directory where the Makefile is stored. But how to add the source code ?

Comment: When all settings are done, run project/build project from the menu in Eclipse, building is processing, how to redirect the output to the Eclipse's console?

Answer (score 6):

Create a new project, make sure to uncheck the "Use default location" option while doing so. Add your source tree path in the location field. Now select "Makefile Project" in the project types window.

In "builder settings" (Project>Properties), uncheck the "use default build command" and add:

```
make -f /<your project location/Makefile
```

If your makefile is named otherwise, you can change it here.

To run your application, add the application in Run Configurations. See full instructions [here](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Fgetting_started%2Fcdt_w_import.htm).

Comment: When all settings are done, run project/build project from the menu in Eclipse, building is processing, how to redirect the output to the Eclipse's console?

Answer (score 3):

Don't say import.

Create a new C/C++ project using the New Project Wizard, and specify the "root folder" as a non-default location of the new project.

See the instructions [here](http://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Fgetting_started%2Fcdt_w_existing_code.htm&cp=13_1_8).

Read "Creating new projects from existing source roots"