# How to build openssl on eclipse cdt

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, openssl, eclipse-cdt

I have downloaded openssl 1.0.1h source on my ubuntu machine. I want to build the source on eclipse cdt but I have no clue how feasible that task is. I can easily make and install openssl using make command but currently i am not looking for that.

So what is the way of building openssl on eclipse?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import C makefile project into eclipse or put in under eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794967/how-to-import-c-makefile-project-into-eclipse-or-put-in-under-eclipse). The instructions apply to all makefile based projects, and not just OpenSSL.