# import GitHub makefile project into eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, makefile, stm32f4discovery

I tried to compile a project of stm32f4 from GitHub on eclipse, this is its link:
https://github.com/piratfm/codec2_m4f

Follow some instructions on internet, I did: Import->c/c++-> Existing code as makefile project->Choose path of project folder and tick Cross Arm GCC in "toolchain for Indexer setting"-> Click finish.

Click build, I got these error in console:

```
make[2]: *** [misc.o] Error 2

make[1]: Leaving directory `C:/Users/abcd/Desktop/codec2_m4f-master/lib'

make[1]: *** [all] Error 2

make: *** [lib] Error 2.
```

and in problem:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type

make[2]: *** [misc.o] Error 2   codec2_m4f-master  C/C++ Problem

make[1]: *** [all] Error 2  codec2_m4f-master  C/C++ Problem

make: *** [lib] Error 2 codec2_m4f-master C/C++ Problem
```

I installed everything to compile and build C/C++ project for stm32f4 on eclipse, I tested it with some simple project as blink led.

Any opinion to fix these problem? or I will run it on Linux platform

Can somebody try building it and upload debug folder?

Thanks

Comment: What you doing ? open Or Import?

Comment: I want to compile it,  some instructions told me using import function to open it in eclipse and compile, for example: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794967/how-to-import-c-makefile-project-into-eclipse-or-put-in-under-eclipse>

Comment: Make sure it compiles from cmd lne first.  After verifying that, you'll have to set up eclipse to use the gcc cross-compile toolchain that is mentioned on github.

Comment: Hi rost0031, you make me get confused, I followed some tutorial on internet to integrate cross ARM gcc toolchain into eclipse, as this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kjvqySyNw20
could you give me another guide to compile on cmd and set up cross arm gcc for github on eclipse ?