# Which IDE is used by DPDK developers, and how do they debug their code?

Tags: eclipse, ide, dpdk

I want to know if there is an IDE that is used by DPDK developers to develop a DPDK. I use the 'make' tool to build DPDK and DPDK example applications. I want to debug the code and want to know if there's any IDE that I can use. DPDK is developed in C language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update: Intel system studio is now supported with free license model. On linux this is supported with eclipse with all tools. Have a try.

I prefer to use GDB with TUI enabled with DPDK library and example build with '-g'. You can achieve this by passing `EXTRA_CFLAGS=" -g " make`. I have also seen people using eclipse with remote gdb too.

based on the follow-up comment, please find the answer to using eclipse IDE on Linux for DPDK setup shared below

Note: I do not use Eclipse IDE but once tried it out C projects with Makefile.

1. as far as I can recollect one needs to install Eclipse with
   Eclipse-CDT plugin.
2. Then create the new project with the option `Makefile exists`.
3. Add the project with files.

Here we have 2 options:

1. add the Makefile of the target build. or
2. add the Makefile of the test application (example l3fwd).

It will be really helpful if either Makefile is edited with `-g` or `EXTRACFLAGS=-g` is passed.

You can check [how to import cmake to eclipse project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794967/how-to-import-c-makefile-project-into-eclipse-or-put-in-under-eclipse).

Comment: Can you tell me how to use eclipse with remote gdb as you mentioned?

Comment: as mentioned in the thread, I have not personally used Eclipse IDE. But as far as I can recollect you will need to install Eclipse with Eclipse-CDT plugin first. Create the new project with option `Makefile exist with the project` with destination for src files to DPDK folder. You can check `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794967/how-to-import-c-makefile-project-into-eclipse-or-put-in-under-eclipse`. So in your case if you run `l3fwd` you should point to `dpdksrc/examples/l3fwd/Makefile`

Comment: Please [edit] to add additional information or explanation, instead of hiding it down here in the comments.

Comment: @Yunnosch thanks for your suggestion, I have added the details in the answer category. Please note, I do not intention have any intention to hide or conceal. Based on the original question I have answered my DEV & Test environment for DPDK

Comment: You might have misunderstood "hide". I did not blame you of something bad. It just might prevent due appreciation of a decent answer, if part of it is not really read by some people. I.e. it was just a recommendation to make the quality of your contribution more apparent.